# How to change nested child's class and return the original parent with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of html template in a string which I need to update. Say:

`var tpl = "<div><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></div>";`

How do I add a class to the `a` tag and return back the updated string? This string template can be entirely customized so the code must not rely on this particular string.

If I do:
`$(tpl).find('a').addClass('myClass')` then the original `tpl` variable will not be affected.

If I do:
`tpl = $(tpl).find('a').addClass('myClass').html()` then I will only get the contents of `a` tag.

So what would be the correct approach?

The contents of `tpl` should in the end be:

`<div><a href="#" class="myClass"><img src="..."></a></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$.fn.end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/) to return original matched set:

```
tpl = $(tpl).find('a').addClass('myClass').end().prop('outerHTML');
```

```js
var tpl = '<div><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></div>';
tpl = $(tpl).find('a').addClass('myClass').end().prop('outerHTML');
console.log(tpl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And if you want to return the parent jq object, not the outer HTML string, remove `prop()`:

```
tpl = $(tpl).find('a').addClass('myClass').end();
```

Comment: Also, Please add that the variable tpl should be declare with a single quote.

Comment: @PathikGandhi But we can guess it is just a question's typo. Feel free to edit answer if you think it really matters

Comment: If is it, Then its ok. :)

Comment: Sorry about the quotes, a typo. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Wow nice, didn't know you could do that. This answer is much better than mine. Up voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your template around a div and go back to it after your modifications.

```js
$(function() {
  var tmpl = '<div><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div>';
  tmpl = jQuery("<div class=\"outer\">")
  .append(tmpl)
  .find('a')
  .addClass('test')
  .parents('.outer')
  .html();
  alert(tmpl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qnLh13b/7/

Comment: But the original variable stay unmodified.

Comment: Then just assign it to that variable. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have no "a-href tag previously", then you can use :-

```
tpl = $(tpl).find('a').eq(0).addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: This is not the question